# Why is $\delta x$ tending to be zero in dy/dx and not $\delta y$ tending to be 0?

Tags: calculus

Why is  $\Delta x $ and not $\Delta y $ written to be tending towards 0 in case when we give limits to form dy/dx.

, $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Can we solve this equation like we solve when there is a = sign and we take denominator towards the other numerator?
Like $$\frac{3}{4}=\frac{6}{8}$$

So we get 24=24.

, $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of a function is often described as the instantaneous rate of change. I will explain this by way of analogy. Say it takes you $10$ seconds to drive $100$m in a car. Your *average* speed is $10$m/s, but it is possible that during those $10$ seconds, sometimes you were going faster, and other times you were going slower. Even in the space of $0.1$ seconds, perhaps your speed changed a little bit during that time. So rather than trying to calculate one's speed over a specific time interval, we instead try to make rigorous the notion of what your speed is at *one particular point*. We do this by calculating the limit
$$
\frac{ds}{dt}=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} \, .
$$
As $t$ gets closer and closer to $0$, there is less and less room for your speed to be changing during that time period. This can be visualised by zooming in on the velocity-time graph. It looks *almost* linear, meaning that, for example, in the space of $0.000001$ seconds, your speed—the rate of change of distance—is pretty much constant.

Because we are considering a limit, it is not possible to 'solve' the above equation in the way you would a fraction. This is because we are not considering any one value of $t$, but rather what happens at $t$ approaches $0$.

Comment: We maybe can’t solve them.But we can write they are equal right

Comment: without the limit.@Joe

Comment: The angle made by dy/dx and delta y/delta x is same.Which means their slope is same.

Comment: $$\frac{ds}{dt} \neq \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$$ in general.

Comment: Reason ? Please share.They should be.Almost equal.@Joe

Comment: @user277768 $\Delta y/\Delta x$ is the slope of the secant line between two points. It is equal to $$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} \, .$$ By contrast, $dy/dx$ represents the slope of the tangent to a point. It is equal to $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} \, .$$ You can read more about the connection between secant lines and tangent lines [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus#Derivative).